# Analytical form of a Histogram of $1-\cos(X)$, $X\sim U(0, 2\pi)$

Tags: distributions, histogram

If I generate a uniform distribution of $X$ ranging from $0$ to $2\pi$ (so $X\sim U(0, 2\pi)$), then the probability distribution of $1-\cos(X)$ appears to be this function:

[image]

Is this an analytical function that I can work with directly? And if so, how do I prove this?

Comment: Based on inspection and some clues in the text, I can guess that it's an arcsine distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution but you'll need to provide more details to know for sure. How is $X$ distributed? If an "even distribution" means "uniform" then there are certain transformations of uniform distributions that are definitely arcsine distributions.

Comment: I just simulated from $N(0, 1)$ and then applied your $1-\cos(x)$ transformation, leading to a [somewhat different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5k3y.png) plot.

Comment: @dave could you try it with a uniform distribution ranging from (0, 2pi)?

Comment: You can find extensive explanations by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=transform+pdf).

Answer (score 5):

We can evaluate the distribution function $F(y)$ of $Y := 1 - \cos(X)$ directly as follows.

To begin with, note that as $X$ ranges over $[0, 2\pi]$, the range of $Y$ is from $0$ (achieved at $X = 0$ or $2\pi$) to $2$ (achieved at $\pi$).  Therefore, for $y < 0$, $F(y) = 0$ and for $y \geq 2$, $F(y) = 1$.

For $y \in [0, 2)$ (it is helpful to draw the graph of $x \mapsto \cos(x)$ on $[0, 2\pi]$ to determine the region $\{x \in [0, 2\pi]: \cos(x) \geq 1 - y\}$. Also keep in mind that the domain of $x \mapsto \arccos(x)$ is $[-1, 1]$ with range $[0, \pi]$, so mirroring is needed for angle that is greater than $\pi$):
\begin{align}
& F(y) = P[1 - \cos(X) \leq y] = P[\cos(X) \geq 1 - y] \\
=& P[X \in [0, \arccos(1 - y)] \cup [2\pi - \arccos(1 - y), 2\pi]] \\
=& \frac{\arccos(1 - y)}{\pi}.
\end{align}

To summarize, the distribution of $Y$ is given by
\begin{align}
F(y) = \begin{cases}
0 & y < 0, \\
\frac{\arccos(1 - y)}{\pi} & 0 \leq y < 2, \\
1 & y \geq 2. 
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Taking derivative of $F$ yields the pdf of $Y$:
\begin{align}
f(y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1 - (1 - y)^2}} & 0 < y < 2, \\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

A graph of $f$ looks as follows, which matches the histogram you simulated. As @Sycorax pointed out in the comment, this is [Arcsine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcsine_distribution) with support $(0, 2)$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result with the delta method: $p(z)=\int_R p(x) \delta(z-(1-cos(x)))dx$. https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities